# how to test ntp servers as real servers that responding without using ping test

Tags: bash, rhel, ping, ntp, chrony

we have bash script that configured the `chrony.conf`

script check if ping is ok on `ntp1` and `ntp2` ( ntp servers )

and then script insert the ntp servers to `/etc/chrony.conf` ( only if ping success )

example from bash script:

```
ping -c 1 ntp1

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
echo "server ntp1 iburst" >> /etc/chrony.conf
else
echo "sorry so much but no ping to ntp1 server , /etc/chrony.conf will not configured "
exit 1
fi


ping -c 1 ntp2
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
echo "server ntp2 iburst" >> /etc/chrony.conf
else
echo "sorry so much but no ping to ntp2 server , /etc/chrony.conf will not configured "
exit 1
fi
```

the problem is that sometimes the user decided to disable the `ping` or `icmp`

**then in that case** the scenario that we checked the ping isn't relevant , and we cant add the lines to `/etc/chrony.conf`

so we want to know how to **test** the `ntp1` and `ntp2` servers in order to add **ntp1** and `ntp2` to chrony configuration

for example if `ntp1` and `ntp2` not seems to be as ntp servers , then we will not add them to chrony configuration

Comment: Use the protocol you need to verify works. You don’t check if a web server is up by sending an email.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1722742/432690).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the NTP servers with `ntpdate` tool.

Something like this:
`OP=$(ntpdate -q ntp1)`

If OP contains Proper Date Data, ntp1 is working. Else try ntp2.

---

Reference : https://www.tunnelsup.com/how-to-test-an-ntp-server-using-ntpdate/
Output :

```
$ ntpdate -q pool.ntp.org  
server 64.71.128.26, stratum 2, offset 1.552116, delay 0.06792  
server 104.236.236.188, stratum 2, offset 1.556884, delay 0.11574  
server 108.59.2.24, stratum 2, offset 1.569006, delay 0.11952  
server 209.114.111.1, stratum 2, offset 1.542965, delay 0.11389  
19 Apr 21:30:06 ntpdate[32062]: step time server 64.71.128.26 offset 1.552116 sec
```

---

A quick comment about your script :
When ntp1 did not respond, you should log it but not exit, rather you should move on to ntp2.
Only when both are non-responsive, you might not want to continue.